# Javascript:Replace single characters after the string

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I'm trying to do something which seems fairly basic, but can't seem to get it working.

I'm trying to strip the characters after the last instance of an underscore.

I have this long Query String:

```
json_data=demo_title=Demo+title&proc1_script=script.sh+parameters&proc1_chk_make=on&outputp2_value=&demo_input_description=hola+mundo&outputp4_visible=on&outputp4_info=&inputdata1_max_pixels=1024000&tag=&outputp1_id=nanana&proc1_src_compresion=zip&proc1_chk_cmake=off&outputp3_description=&outputp3_value=&inputdata1_description=input+data+description&inputp2_description=bien%3F&inputp3_description=funciona&proc1_cmake=-D+CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE%3Astring%3DRelease+&outputp2_visible=on&outputp3_visible=on&outputp1_type=header&inputp1_type=text&demo_params_description=va+bien&outputp1_description=&inputdata1_type=image2d&proc1_chk_script=off&demo_result_description=win%3F&outputp2_id=nanfdsvfa&inputp1_description=funciona&demo_wait_description=boh&outputp4_description=&inputp2_type=integer&inputp2_id=papapa&outputp1_value=&outputp3_id=nananartrtrt&inputp3_id=pepepe&outputp3_type=header&inputp3_visible=+off&outputp1_visible=on&inputdata1_id=id_lsd&outputp4_value=&inputp2_visible=on&proc1_source=lsd-1.5.zip&inputp3_value=si&proc1_make=-j4+-C+&images_config_file=cfgmydemo.cfg&outputp2_type=header&proc1_subdir=xxx-1.5&proc1_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ipol.im%2Fpub%2Falgo%2F...&inputdata1_image_depth=1x8i&inputp1_id=popopo&inputp1_value=si&inputp2_value=no&demo_data_filename=data_saved.cfg&inputdata1_info=info_lsd&outputp3_info=&inputdata1_image_format=.pgm&outputp1_info=&inputdata1_compress=False&inputp1_visible=on&proc1_id=lsd&outputp4_id=nana&outputp2_description=&outputp4_type=header&outputp2_info=&inputp3_type=float&&tag&inputp4_iddcksmdclk&inputp4_typetext&inputp4_descriptionkldmsclk&inputp4_valueklcdmkl&inputp4_infoclkdmscdl
```

Now I replace the separator `=` in separator `%24+` and `&` in `+%23+` using fr=fr.replace(/\&/g,"+%23+");

```
            Separator


javascript              Mako           

  =                       %24+
  &                       +%23+
```

But the result is:

```
   json_data%24+demo_title%24+Demo+title+%23+proc1_script%24+script.sh+parameters+%23+proc1_chk_make%24+on+%23+outputp2_value%24++%23+demo_input_description%24+hola+mundo+%23+outputp4_visible%24+on+%23+outputp4_info%24++%23+inputdata1_max_pixels%24+1024000+%23+tag%24++%23+outputp1_id%24+nanana+%23+proc1_src_compresion%24+zip+%23+proc1_chk_cmake%24+off+%23+outputp3_description%24++%23+outputp3_value%24++%23+inputdata1_description%24+input+data+description+%23+inputp2_description%24+bien%3F+%23+inputp3_description%24+funciona+%23+proc1_cmake%24+-D+CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE%3Astring%3DRelease++%23+outputp2_visible%24+on+%23+outputp3_visible%24+on+%23+outputp1_type%24+header+%23+inputp1_type%24+text+%23+demo_params_description%24+va+bien+%23+outputp1_description%24++%23+inputdata1_type%24+image2d+%23+proc1_chk_script%24+off+%23+demo_result_description%24+win%3F+%23+outputp2_id%24+nanfdsvfa+%23+inputp1_description%24+funciona+%23+demo_wait_description%24+boh+%23+outputp4_description%24++%23+inputp2_type%24+integer+%23+inputp2_id%24+papapa+%23+outputp1_value%24++%23+outputp3_id%24+nananartrtrt+%23+inputp3_id%24+pepepe+%23+outputp3_type%24+header+%23+inputp3_visible%24++off+%23+outputp1_visible%24+on+%23+inputdata1_id%24+id_lsd+%23+outputp4_value%24++%23+inputp2_visible%24+on+%23+proc1_source%24+lsd-1.5.zip+%23+inputp3_value%24+si+%23+proc1_make%24+-j4+-C++%23+images_config_file%24+cfgmydemo.cfg+%23+outputp2_type%24+header+%23+proc1_subdir%24+xxx-1.5+%23+proc1_url%24+http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ipol.im%2Fpub%2Falgo%2F...+%23+inputdata1_image_depth%24+1x8i+%23+inputp1_id%24+popopo+%23+inputp1_value%24+si+%23+inputp2_value%24+no+%23+demo_data_filename%24+data_saved.cfg+%23+inputdata1_info%24+info_lsd+%23+outputp3_info%24++%23+inputdata1_image_format%24+.pgm+%23+outputp1_info%24++%23+inputdata1_compress%24+False+%23+inputp1_visible%24+on+%23+proc1_id%24+lsd+%23+outputp4_id%24+nana+%23+outputp2_description%24++%23+outputp4_type%24+header+%23+outputp2_info%24++%23+inputp3_type%24+float+%23++%23+tag+%23+inputp4_iddcksmdclk+%23+inputp4_typetext+%23+inputp4_descriptionkldmsclk+%23+inputp4_valueklcdmkl+%23+inputp4_infoclkdmscdl
```

Now I am interested how to replace this `=` after the value `jsondata`.
Explain: 
In the Query string there is the string json_data+%23+ and this +%23+ I want replace to =
How?

Comment: your question is unclear.  Do you want to replace the characters after the last instance of "_" replace an `=` after a given value, or something else?

Comment: I want to change the character = after the string tag.

Comment: tag+%23+ after with replace tag=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strip the characters after the last instance of an underscore:

```
json_data.substring(0, json_data.lastIndexOf("_"));
```

Replace +%23+ with =

```
json_data.replace("+%23+", "=");
```

However, if you're trying to turn all the %xx into what they're supposed to be, you should url decode the string instead. 
Which would probably have to be something like:

```
decodeURIComponent((json_data).replace('+', '%20'));
```